# How do I get a search match from a list of strings in Haskell?

Tags: string, list, haskell, io

How do I get a search match from a list of strings in Haskell?

```
module Main
    where
import List
import IO
import Monad

getLines = liftM lines . readFile

main = do
    putStrLn "Please enter your name: "
    name <- getLine
    list <- getLines "list.txt"
   -- mapM_ putStrLn list -- this part is to list out the input of lists
```

Comment: How is the content of list.txt formatted? I'm guessing that you want to filter for lines that contain the word name?

Answer (score 12):

The first thing to do, the all-important first principle, is to get as much of the thinking out of `main` or out of `IO` as possible. `main` should where possible contain all the `IO` and maybe nothing but `IO` decorated with pure terms you define elsewhere in the module. Your `getLines` is mixing them unnecessarily.

So, to get that out of the way, we should have a `main` that is something like

```
main = 
   do putStrLn "What is your name?"
      name <- getContents
      names <- readFile "names.txt"
      putStrLn (frankJ name names)
```

-- or maybe the more austere segregation of `IO` from all else that we get from:

```
main = 
   do putStrLn greeting
      name <- getContents
      names <- readFile nameFile
      putStrLn (frankJ name names)
```

together with the 'pure' terms:

```
greeting, nameFile :: String
greeting = "What is your name?"
nameFile = "names.txt"
```

Either way, we are now really in Haskell-land: the problem is now to figure out what the pure *function*:

```
 frankJ :: String -> String -> String
```

should be.

We might start with a simple matching function: we get a match when the first string appears on a list of strings:

```
 match :: String -> [String] -> Bool
 match name namelist = name `elem` namelist  
 -- pretty clever, that!
```

or we might want to normalize a bit, so that white space at the beginning and end of the name we are given and the names on the list doesn't affect the match.  Here's a rather shabby way to do that:

```
 clean :: String -> String
 clean =  reverse . omitSpaces . reverse . omitSpaces
   where omitSpaces = dropWhile (== ' ')
```

Then we can improve on our old `match`, i.e. `elem`:

```
 matchClean :: String -> [String] -> Bool
 matchClean name namelist = match (clean name) (map clean namelist)
```

Now we need to follow the types, figuring out how to fit the type of, say, `matchClean:: String -> [String] -> Bool` with that of `frankJ :: String -> String -> String`.  We want to fit it inside our definition of `frankJ`.

Thus, to 'provide input' for `matchClean`, we need a function to take us from a long string with newlines to the list of stings (the names) that `matchClean` needs: that's the Prelude function `lines`.

But we also need to decide what to do with the `Bool` that `matchClean` yields as value; `frankJ`, as we have it, returns a `String`. Let us continue with simple-minded decomposition of the problem:

```
response :: Bool -> String
response False = "We're sorry, your name does not appear on the list, please leave."
response True = "Hey, you're on the A-list, welcome!"
```

Now we have materials we can compose into a reasonable candidate for the function `frankJ :: String -> String -> String` that we are feeding into our `IO` machine defined in `main`:

```
frankJ name nametext = response (matchClean name (lines nametext))

-- or maybe the fancier:  
-- frankJ name = response . matchClean name . lines
-- given a name, this 
--     - pipes the nametext through the lines function, splitting it,
--     - decides whether the given name matches, and then 
--     - calculates the 'response' string
```

So here, almost everything is a matter of pure functions, and it is easy to see how to emend things for further refinement.  For example, maybe the name entered and the lines of the text file should be further normalized. Internals spaces should be restricted to one space, before the comparison.  Or maybe there is a comma in lines on the list since people are listed as "lastname, firstname", etc. etc.  Or maybe we want the response function to use the person's name:

```
personalResponse :: String -> Bool -> String
personalResponse name False = name ++ " is a loser, as far as I can tell, get out!"
personalResponse name True  = "Ah, our old friend " ++ name ++ "! Welcome!"
```

together with

```
frankJpersonal name = personalResponse name . matchClean name . lines
```

Of course there are a million ways of going about this.  For example, there are `regex` libraries.  The excellent and simple `Data.List.Split` from Hackage might also be of use, but I'm not sure it can be used by Hugs, which you might be using.

I note that you are using old-fashioned names for the imported modules.  What I have written uses only the Prelude so imports are unnecessary, but the other modules are now called "System.IO", "Data.List" and "Control.Monad" in accordance with the hierarhical naming system.  I wonder if you are using an old tutorial or manual.  Maybe the pleasant 'Learn You a Haskell' site would be better?  He affirms he's using `ghc` but I think that won't affect much.

Answer (score 3):

If you wan't a list of all lines in your list.txt that contain the name,
you can simply use

```
filter (isInfixOf name) list
```

but I'm not sure if I understood your question correct.